# Website dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

Is there any javascript library that I can use to serve HTML content? I would like to create a DIV that the content can be dynamically changed.

```
<div id="header">
  <h2>Header here</h2>
</div>

<div id="dynamic-content">
  <p>-- Dynamic content here --</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <h3>Footer</h3>
</div>
```

I'm planning to use jQuery for this, just retrieving the HTML markup from the server and then use jQuery's `html()` function to replace the content of `#dynamic-content`. I'm just curious if this is practical if the retrived HTML markup is "large", lets say a whole article.

Is there a simple JavaScript templating framework for this? Or can I even use templating JS frameworks for this?

Comment: To do this in a more "modern" way you'd want to use a JS framework like Angular, Knockout or others that have 2 way data binding. There is a slight learning curve associated with these though. I know plenty of cases where I've polled/loaded content in app, on the fly with jQuery. I don't think there's a wrong or right way.

Comment: If you're planning on passing a large string of html, you would likely be better off using a client-side templating solution (Handlebars, Mustache, etc.)

Comment: @GregJennings If I retrieve the HTML markup from the server and then feeding that markup to Handlerbars or Mustache okay?

Comment: @G.Thompson Do I really need data binding? And what can be the implementation of that? I'm just looking for a better way to replace the markup inside a DIV.

Comment: I guess it's probably best you better describe your exact situations/needs and maybe I can think of a better solution. What do you mean by dynamically changed and how? Also, no you don't need data binding but it's an option.

Comment: @G.Thompson All I want is when a user clicks on a link, example view this article. The `dynamic-content` will have the article. And if the user clicks on another link, lets say `Categories`, the `dynamic-content` will have the categories, replacing the article in it previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**--Helper--**

```
var uiHelper = function () {

    var htmls = {};

    var getHTML = function (options) {
        /// <summary>Returns HTML in a string format</summary>
        /// <param name="options" type="object">options{url:The url to the file with the HTML,successCallback:function,errorCallback:function,isAsync:true||false,cache:true|false}</param>

        function xhrSuccess() {
            if (this.cache) { htmls[this.url] = this.responseText; };

            if (this.successCallback) {
                this.successCallback.apply(this.responseText, this.arguments);
            } else {
                return htmls[this.url];
            };
        };
        function xhrError() {

            if (this.errorCallback) {
                this.errorCallback.apply(this.statusText);
            } else {
                return this.statusText;
            };
        };

        if (!htmls[options.url]) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", options.url, options.isAsync);
            xmlhttp.cache = options.cache || false;
            xmlhttp.url = options.url;
            xmlhttp.onload = xhrSuccess;
            xmlhttp.onerror = xhrError;
            xmlhttp.successCallback = options.successCallback || undefined;
            xmlhttp.errorCallback = options.errorCallback || undefined;
            xmlhttp.send();
        } else {

            if (options.successCallback) {
                options.successCallback.apply(htmls[options.url], this.arguments);
            } else {
                return htmls[options.url];
            };
        };
    };

    return {
        getHTML: getHTML
    };
}();
```

**--Usage---**

```
    uiHelper.getHTML({
        url: url, isAsync: true, cache: false, successCallback: function () {

            document.getElementById('dynamicContent').innerHTML = this;
        }
    });
```

**--Your HTML---**

```
<div id="header">
  <h2>Header here</h2>
</div>

<div id="dynamic-content">
  <p id='dynamicContent'>-- Dynamic content here --</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <h3>Footer</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,I recommend you this jquery plugin: jquery.tmpl

github: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

this is the introduction：

ppt: http://skilldrick.co.uk/tmpl/

article: http://footyntech.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/simple-javascript-templating-with-jquery-tmpl/

: )

Comment: So retrieving the HTML markup from the server is just basically feeding it to jQuery? Then call `tmpl`?

Comment: We retrieving the data in json from the server(like: jquery ajax or serverSide language eg php, java, nodejs), and use jquery.tmpl to make html markup.That reduce the needless time to transfer html markup. And here is an ajax example
    <ul id="movieList"></ul>  
    <script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">  
      <li><b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})</li>  
</script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $.get("/your/server/api.json/",function(response){
        $( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( response ).appendTo( "#movieList" );                 
    },"json");
</script>